# Use known eigenvalues to express eigenvalues of multiple and exponent of matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say we have a matrix $\mathbf{B}$

$$
\mathbf{B}=\begin{pmatrix}
6&0&0\\
2&-3&-4\\
-5&2&3 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We know the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=6$, $\lambda_2=-1$ and $\lambda_3=1$. We're then asked to express the eigenvalues for

$$2\mathbf{B}^2+\mathbf{I}$$

I assume that for any matrix raised to the power $k$ (where $k$ is a positive integer), it's associated eigenvalues are $\lambda^k$. I also assume that for any matrix multiplied by some number $k$, it's associated eigenvalues will be $k\lambda$. Finally, for any matrix added to a multiple (which is any number for $k$) of an identity matrix, $\mathbf{B}+k\mathbf{I}$, the eigenvalues will be $\lambda+k$. So for the eigenvalue $\lambda_1=6$ for $2\mathbf{B}^2+\mathbf{I}$ is

$$
2\times(6)^2+1=73
$$

Have I correctly worked this out?

Comment: only if you know how to prove all your 'assume' statements

Comment: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227732/relationship-between-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-and-its-square) This might help. More general and has a way to prove

Comment: Do you know the Jordan-form?

Comment: @whitelined the title of your question doesn't really express what you are looking for. Could you reword it e.g. *Use known eigenvalues of $B$ to express those of $B^2+I$*

Answer (score 1):

You're right. If $(\lambda,u)$ is an eigenpair of $\bf{B},$ then $$\begin{aligned}\left(\bf{B}^2+\bf{I}\right)u&={\bf{B}}({\bf{B}}u)+{\bf{I}}u\\
&={\bf{B}}\lambda u+u\\&=\lambda({\bf{B}}u)+u\\&=(\lambda ^2+1)u\end{aligned}$$

Thus $(\lambda ^2 +1, u)$ is an eigenpair of $\bf{B}^2+\bf{I}.$

Answer (score 0):

You are right. A generalization reads as follows: If $A$ is a real or complex square matrix then we denote the set of eigenvalues of $A$ by $\sigma(A)$. If $p$ is a polynomial then we have the "spectral mapping theorem":

$$ \sigma (p(A)) =p( \sigma(A)).$$